# Why the function canvas of tkinter don't work?

Tags: python, tkinter

So i started a project on python with Tk and i wanted to create a rectangle, i know how to do it i just need to create a Canvas and use the methods create_rectangle but nothing append. So i started to debug and see whats wrong. And for debug i set the bg color of my canvas to blue but nothing append to !! i schearch everywere but i dont see what's wrong !! And also i create a test program and also nothing append !!

My little test program:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

root = Tk()

root.geometry('300x300')

c = tk.Canvas(root, width=250, height=300, bg="blue")
c.pack

root.mainloop()
```

(i use PyCharm for my ide)

Please help me !!

Comment: The two import statements together are really bad practice.  Just use the second statement, `import tkinter as tk`.

Comment: If omer's answer answered your question, and it was just a matter of a missing parentheses, please accept their answer (so others know the question is closed).

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `c.pack()`. You forgot the parentheses:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

root = Tk()

root.geometry('300x300')

c = tk.Canvas(root, width=250, height=300, bg="blue")
c.pack()

root.mainloop()
```